# maven more than one repo and one mirror and none mirror que

Tags: maven, repository

i'm china ,english may be not currect.

I found that setting multiple mirrors is invalid, but setting repo lacks can achieve recursive warehouse download dependencies, but compared with mirror download speed, it is very short. The two warehouses I set up are my domestic warehouses here, and there is no such thing as slow network speed across countries. Why is it very slow without configuring mirror, and once mirror is configured, my company's private warehouse cannot download dependencies. Is there something wrong with my usage method? What should I do if I want to configure multiple warehouses and configure mirror to ensure network speed?

```
    <profile>
        <id>aliyunRepository</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>companyRepository</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>companyRepository</id>
                <name>companyRepository</name>
                <url>http://maven.nexus.service.public.xxx.com/repository/maven/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>aliyunRepository</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>companyRepository</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

end